# How to add a new button to windows explorer?

Tags: windows, button, toolbar, windows-shell

I want to know how to add a new button in windows explorer. I don't want to create a new toolbar. I just want to add a  new button in the same windows explorer standard buttons toolbar and not IE.

I appreciate any help possible.

Regards

Comment: Which version of Windows? XP or Vista?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that..... I'm looking to add a button to Vista and 7 toolbands. The IShellBrowser SetToolbarItems() only works with XP.

I just found that one yesterday and forgot to update the question. Still I'm looking for the appropriate method to manipulate the Vista and 7 toolbars, if any....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this article which seems to satisfy my desires... I'm currently on the path of starting development with the new interfaces and will let you know if they work as needed.

The article: http://www.windowsvistaplace.com/shell-namespace-extension-adding-custom-command-module-items/windows-vista#comment-13115

Thanks for everyone who replied/commented on my question

Answer (score 1):

I got something.

first an article:
http://www.askvg.com/how-to-customize-windows-explorer-command-bar that I found searching for `{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}` which is the FolderType CLSID for **Generic**.

You find those in the windows registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` under the key:

`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes`

Read the article it's pretty informative! But if you wanna have code already:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected\0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected\0\{E7E304C4-3C99-49BD-9E5F-980D15103C50}]
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\shell32.dll,3"
"InfoTip"="some bla bla "
"Title"="a button!"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected\0\{E7E304C4-3C99-49BD-9E5F-980D15103C50}\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected\0\{E7E304C4-3C99-49BD-9E5F-980D15103C50}\shell\InvokeTask]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected\0\{E7E304C4-3C99-49BD-9E5F-980D15103C50}\shell\InvokeTask\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\DUMMYUSER\\hello.exe\""
```

Rigth in the middle you have a **random CLSID** created along with the **Title** aka button text or label, **InfoTip** which appears when hovering with the cursor and Icon which sadly doesn't work. At the end there is the **command** to execute. Change those to your desire, save as a *.reg and just run it.

A bummer has to be said: Does **not work** on Non-Admin users! I tried it but seems you cannot just replace `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is supported.

You could probably inject into the process and subclass the window and add the toolbar button if hacky solutions are OK.

Comment: Well, I'm in the process of believing that. But still hoping to find a solution. Hopefully, there is one... Hacky solutions are fine by me :)